# How do make a clipped views recieve touch events in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, events, touch

When a UITableView does not completely fit in its superview, the parts that are clipped are not scrollable. You can only scroll the intersection of the table view and its superview. I believe this type of event handling problem happens with any combination of UIViews, not just table views. Is there a property or something I can turn on to allow clipped areas to still accept touch events?

```
 _______
|       |
|    ___|__
|   |______|
|   |______|
|   |______|
|___|______|
    |______|
```

Here is the rather simple example of how the above layout was achieved.

```
UIView* parentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 150)];
UITableView* childView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 150)];
[self.view addSubview:parentView];
[self.parentView addSubview:childView];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to make your parent view override `- pointInside:withEvent:` to check if the point is inside its subview, and return YES if it is. (Basically, the parent view needs to return YES if the touch is inside it *or* the tableview)

Something like:

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint pointInTableView = [tableView convertPoint:point fromView:self];
    return [super pointInside:point withEvent:event] || [tableView pointInside:pointInTableView withEvent:event];
}
```